# Updated background on Hilbert 16th problem?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, open-problems, limit-cycles

What is the current situation of the second part of the [Hilbert 16th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_sixteenth_problem#The_second_part_of_Hilbert's_16th_problem)? What are the most updated news on this problem?

Comment: (from wikipedia) the second part is: *The determination of the upper bound for the number of limit cycles in two-dimensional polynomial vector fields of degree $n$ and an investigation of their relative positions*

Comment: @Ycor  Thank  you  for  adding  the  tag "limit cycle"!

Comment: @YCor  and  also  adding the  wikipedia link  and  editting the title.

Comment: Shall we play update the title to optimize the English? “Updated Background on Hilbert’s 16th Problem”?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas  Thanks for your comment. Do you have a suggestion for revision of the title?

Comment: My comment did suggest a minor improvement (from “the Hilbert 16th Problem” to “Hilbert’s 16th Problem”). This does not affect readability of your question, and I only posted it as someone else had already edited the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An update from April 2018 is given by [Patrick Speissegger](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03585).

The idea, going back to Poincaré, is to reduce the two-dimensional counting problem (counting limit cycles in the plane) to a one-dimensional counting problem (counting certain points on a line). Roussarie (1998) showed that Hilbert’s 16th problem follows if a certain "finite cyclicity conjecture" holds. A tameness condition called "o-minimality" allows to reformulate Roussarie's conjecture as a conjecture of o-minimality. Speissegger discusses special cases where o-minimality can be proven and proposes this approach as a promising way to prove Hilbert's 16th problem.

Comment: Dear  Prof.  Beenakker   Thank  you very much  and  my previous +1   for  your  valuable  answer  and  sorryf or my  late  acceptance